# DataFrame create additional interval/range/period column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, range

I have a dataframe starting from August 2019 up until April 2020.

I would like to add a column/categorical variable to this dataframe and afterwards group and aggregate by this newly introduced column.

I have a date column in this dataframe.
`type(df["Date"].iloc[0])` and it evaluates to datetime.date

I have also a column in this dataframe indicating the week `df["Week]`.

So far I have written a function, which classifies based on the week:

```
def time_intervals(week):
    if 33 <= week < 35:
        return "Interval 1"
    elif 35 <= week < 37:
        return "Interval 2"
    ....
```

And then mapped this function to an existing column.
`df["Interval"] = df["Week"].map(time_intervals)`

Now this is not the smartest solution and will definitely cause an issue, once the data overlaps between 2019 and 2020. Is there a smarter way to create such intervals in pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

What about defining the number of weeks from the min date and using pd.cut to define the intervals which seems to be every two weeks, example:

```
idx = pd.date_range('2019-08-01', '2020-04-30', freq='1D')
data = np.random.rand(len(idx))

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=data), index=idx)
min_date = df.index.min()

# Number of weeks from min date
df['week_from_start'] = (df.index - min_date).days//7
bins = [x for x in range(0, df['week_from_start'].max()+2, 2)]

# Define intervals using cut and some predefined bins
df['Interval'] = pd.cut(df['week_from_start'], bins, labels=False, right=False)

# Convert intervals from integers to strings
df['Interval'] = 'Interval ' + (df['Interval'] + 1).astype(str)
df['Interval'].iloc[[1,50,100]]

# 2019-08-02    Interval 1
# 2019-09-20    Interval 4
# 2019-11-09    Interval 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of the pd.cut functionality. I have tried something like this: `df["binned"] = pd.cut(df["Submit Date"], bins = 18)`. This produced an acceptable outcome. The type of `df["Submit Date"]` is a timestamp, so it seems to work. If I do this though with an object of type datetime.date, I get an error message. Not sure, why, but that is not part of the question.

Comment: pd cut is for a continuos variable, like float or int, you cannot use it from strings, datetime, timedeltas, etc.